# How to split a column of defined strings written without spaces in pandas, e.g. appleorange to apple orange?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a code in python that splits a column value in a pandas dataframe. This column will have values like `appleorangemango` that I want to split to `apple orange mango`. I will have a large set of unique words that I will split with respect to them.

Assume that I have this dataframe called `unique_fruits`:

| unique_fruits |
| --- |
| mango |
| apple |
| orange |
| apricot |
| peach |

And another dataframe of fruits that are written without spaces called `my_fruits`:

| my_fruits |
| --- |
| mango |
|  |
| apricotapple |
| orangemango peach |
| banana |

Please note that `banana` is not in `unique_fruits` dataframe. Also, sometimes the column can contain spaces as in `orangemango peach`. Finally, the column can be a single fruit or blank as in the first and second rows of `my_fruits`.

I am planning to read an excel file and save it to a dataframe. Then, try to find out patterns that I can split based on them. If I found something new, then I will get a list of unknown words. I will manually add the new splitted versions of the unknown words and then repeat until I feel that everything is perfect or almost perfect.

An example of unknown words is `bananastrawberry`. Both of `banana` and `strawberry` are new unknown words that I will add to `unique_fruits` dataframe then re-run the code.

If I have `pine`, `apple` and `pineapple` added to `unique_fruits`, then I prefer to have it as `pineapple`. I will split only if I don't have `pineapple` in `unique_fruits`.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck/what's stopping you from doing exactly as you say you'll do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex out of your `unique_fruits`, with the elements sorted by length descending so that longer fruits are first (this will then match `pineapple` in preference to `pine` and `apple`), and then use that to split the strings in `my_fruits`, before joining them back together with a space:

```py
uf = df1['unique_fruits'].to_list()
uf.sort(key=lambda v:-len(v))
# ['apricot', 'orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'peach']

regex = r'(' + '|'.join(list(map(re.escape, uf))) + r')|\s+'
# '(apricot|orange|mango|apple|peach)|\\s+'

df['my_fruits'] = df['my_fruits'].apply(lambda s:' '.join(filter(None, re.split(regex, s))))
#             my_fruits
# 0               mango
# 1       apricot apple
# 2  orange mango peach
# 3              banana
```